# psycopg2 cursor fetchall order of resultset

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.7, postgresql-9.4

I have an application server API which connects to our postgres backend and executes a query which **HAS `ORDER BY`** clause, using the psycopg2 connection and cursor objects.

When I invoke [cursor.fetchall()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall), can I assume that the order of the tuples in the resultset will ALWAYS be the same exact order determined by the `ORDER BY` clause in the executed query?

In other words, can I safely assume that the psycopg2.cursor does not jumble up the original order of the tuples of the resultset?

Thank you,
Pranav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, order is preserved.

the query has already been executed and the results are available. fetchone(), fetchmany() and fetchall() retain the original order of the cursor result list.